# Mongo Mongoose - How to dynamically pick the value for $in operator inside a condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am ierating through an object with key value pairs, where the value is an array of objects. If certain prop (lets say title) is already in the db, I do not want to save that object containing same title. When I hard code the title as a string, it works fine If I pass a map iteration to $in, nothing works (the objects are being saved in all cases then).
What am I doing wrong?

```
 for (let key in reports) {
            const condition = reports[key].map((x) => {
                return x.title;
            });
            await Product.findOneAndUpdate({
                    "name": key
                },
                [
                    {
                        "$set": {
                            "reports": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    {
                                        "$in": [
                                            //this works as expected:
                                            "IAmProduct1",
                                            "$reports.title"

                                            //this does Not work when iterating:
                                            // condition,
                                            // "$reports.title"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$reports",
                                    {
                                        "$concatArrays": [
                                            "$reports",
                                            reports[key]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ], {new: true}) 
         }
```

Comment: i guess, you put `condition` inside array, `{$in: [condition]} `. the operator `$in` should be use one array, `{$in: condition}`. cmiiaw.

Comment: that doesnt change anything unfortunately

Comment: did you already try to check if the variable `condition` return any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `reports[key].map((x) => { return x.title; })` (or just `reports[key].map(x => x.title)`) returns an **array** rather than a string:

```
const reports = { key1: [{ title: "IAmProduct1" }] };

print(reports['key1'].map(x => x.title));

-> [ 'IAmProduct1' ]
```

Which is not

```
'IAmProduct1'
```

Maybe [$setUnion](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) would be simpler:

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name": key },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            reports: { $setUnion: ["$reports", reports[key]] }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Or put the condition in your filter, should be much more efficient:

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name": key, "reports.title": {$ne: condition } },
   [
      {
         "$set": {
            "reports": {
               "$concatArrays": [
                  "$reports",
                  reports[key]
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   { new: true }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. so I tried to do condition.toString to make it a string but still in all cases the data is being added even when it shouldnt. I also tried your solution where I put the condition in the filter but that also doesnt change anything. If title is already presend in one object/report in db, im still adding more reprots with same title. Your other solution with aggregate, Im not sure how to integrate it with the findAndupdate?

Comment: `condition.toString` does not help. Either use `condition[0]` for run another loop over the items.

Comment: thank you, now it works. Can I ask why its more efficient to search for the prop inside filter than in a condition?

Comment: When a document does not match, then it is not processed/updated at all. Thus it is more efficient.